# Can't Connect Visual Studio Team Services (VSO) to Jenkins Instance

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops

I'm trying to follow the steps layed out in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/07/12/jenkins-queue-job-build-task/.

It seems pretty straightforward, but I keep getting invalid login error when trying to queue a build. Right now we are using azure active directory for our jenkins security provider, which I'm assuming is why it might not be working. Does this service only work when using the basic jenkins authentication?

I added my user and pass for azure, but of course they are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is caused by the AAD authentication. The work around for this is creating an API Token in Jenkins after login and then use the "User ID" and "API Token" as username and password when you add Jenkins service endpoint in VSTS.
[image]

Comment: This seemed to work, although VSO is having trouble triggering the build now, it hits the build url, but then sends back a 403 status code

Comment: @ThePaxBisonica Can you share the logs? I cannot see this issue at my side.